# Converting JSON to NSData for Archival

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I’m trying to archive one of my classes via NSCoding but one of the properties is JSON. I’m using SwiftyJSON to convert the JSON to NSData with the encodeWithCoder method but I occasionally get a fatal error: “‘NSInvalidArgumentException’, reason: ‘*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Instead of converting the JSON to NSData I converted it to a String and then encoded that instead. That’s been working for me.

Comment: Simplest yet best. solution. ever.